# Remove last directory when copying files in Ant script

Tags: regex, ant

How can I copy files to a directory one level up?

I've looked at [`cutdirsmapper`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) but it strips leading directories whereas I want to strip the last directory. From the example in the manual, the source filename `foo/bar/A.txt` should be copied to `foo/A.txt`.

This is what I have so far:

```
<copy todir="../vendor">
    <fileset dir="${resources}" includes="Bootstrap/2.2.1/" />
    <fileset dir="${resources}" includes="FontAwesome/4.2.0/" />
    <fileset dir="${resources}" includes="jQuery/2.1.1/" />
</copy>
```

I end up with folders such as `../vendor/Bootstrap/2.2.1/` containing the third-party libraries but I'm looking to copy the contents of `${resources}/Bootstrap/2.2.1/` into `../vendor/Bootstrap/`.

I have tried using the `regexpmapper` like this:

```
<regexpmapper from="^(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)$$" to="\1/\3" handledirsep="true" />
```

This does not work due to subfolders inside `Bootstrap/2.2.1/` (for example `css`, `js`, `img`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, this regexpmapper seemed to do the job:

```
<regexpmapper from="^([^\/]+)/[^\/]+/(.*)$$" to="\1/\2" handledirsep="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a [scriptmapper](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#script-mapper)?

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── src
│   └── foo
│       └── bar
│           ├── 1.0
│           │   └── B.txt
│           └── A.txt
└── target
    └── foo
        ├── A.txt
        └── bar
            └── B.txt
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <target name="build">

    <copy todir="target" includeEmptyDirs="false">
      <fileset dir="src"/>
      <scriptmapper language="javascript">
        importClass(java.io.File);

        src = new File(source);
        trg = new File(src.getParentFile().getParentFile(), src.getName());

        self.addMappedName(trg);
      </scriptmapper>
    </copy>

  </target>

</project>
```